# Is it a good practice to use nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) in Serilog SQL Server logging?

Tags: .net-core, serilog, serilog-sinks-mssqlserver

I'm implementing a custom log table for Serilog SQL Server database logging. I notice that almost all text columns are default to nvarchar(max). I know varchar should be sufficient for us but are not sure if there is a need for messages to exceed 8000 characters. I'm kind of new to this. Is varchar(max) necessary for general application logging?

Please tell your opinions based on your experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I'm implementing a custom log table for Serilog SQL Server database logging"_ - may I ask **why** you think that's a good idea?

Comment: _"I know varchar should be sufficient for us"_ - even if logging directly to an RDBMS was a good idea (and it isn't), you are incorrect here: `varchar` _cannot_ store non-default-codepage (usually Windows-1252) text - so if you're trying to log an error containing user-supplied input containing emoji then it will fail catastrophically - leaving you with no indication there's a problem in the first place. Don't do this.

Comment: I agree with you that I should stick with nvarchar. Not sure you are asking about the custom table or logging to SQL Server database in general. We log to text files and database. The logs in the database allow us to do query and reports.

Comment: I totally understand wanting to query logs later-on, which is fine - but that's best done by using a separate background process to insert into the db from log-files on disk, rather than directly inserting for every `.Log(...)` call.